# Что же код не работает?

Tags: ajax, php, html, javascript

```
function book()
{
    var name = document.book.name.value;
    var avtor = document.book.avtor.value;
    var opis = document.book.opis.value;

    request.open("POST", 'chench_p.php', true);
    request.onreadystatechange = otvet;
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send('name='+name);
}
function otvet () {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            var ress = request.responseText;
            alert (ress);
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, почему код не пашет? К ajax подключился. (Код не вылаживал, но он работает.)

В PHP:

```
<?
echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

Comment: И что именно там не работает?=3 Посмотрите отладчиком - получает ли он name, что передаёт и какой приходит статус ответа и сам ответ)

А то вдруг он null передаёт, пустоту и принимает?)

Comment: Или может request undefined

Comment: а каким отладчиком надо пользоваться?А я ведь правильно в html написал?-=
<input type="button"  value="Добавить" onClick="book();">

Comment: А где входные и выходные переменные? (integer и т. п.)

Comment: Лучше всего firebug (Дополнение для Firefox)

Comment: Пишет что book() не функция(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция book() не должна совпадать с именем формы book

```
"document.book."
```

Comment: Да, вот только понял. ) Спс.